# kubernetes: How to reduce log level in scheduler

Tags: kubernetes

The size of log generated by k8s scheduler is so big.

How i can change log level(info, debug, warn) of scheduler in k8s cluster already established ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml` on your master node; modify `--v=<0-9>` (smaller number to reduce verbose). If you are using cloud provided K8s, you need to check their document if they allow you to configure the verbose level.

Comment: Does this configuration keep after a cluster machine restart?.

Comment: yup, changes made to the yaml will persist.

Comment: Do i need  restart the scheduler ?. If yes, how please ?

Comment: This file is watch by kubelet, once you saved it kubelet will restart kube-scheduler (static pod)

Answer (score 1):

Edit the log level option

```
--v=2
```

in the unit file, or the environment file. Then restart the scheduler

Comment: Does this configuration keep after a cluster machine restart?.

Comment: of course, this is written on a file